# How to write to a memory address contained in a register?

Tags: assembly, avr

I'm taking my first assembly class and I'm a little unsure of how to write to consecutive memory locations.

EDIT: 
I looked at the AVR Assembler instructions and came up with the following:

```
.cseg   ; current segment is code
.org 0  ; begin assembling at memory address 0

    clr r27
    ldi r26, $60
    ldi r16, 0x00   ; set initial loop counter to 0

lp:                     ; on each iteration
        st X+, r16      ; load current number from 0x00-0x0F into memory (increment X)
        inc r16         ; increment r16
        cpi r16, 0x10   ; compare current value of r16 to max value
        breq done       ; done if max value reached
        rjmp lp         ; otherwise loop again

done: jmp done
```

Am I using X correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform an indirect operation, but those can only be performed from X, Y, and Z. You will need to use one of those and perform a post-increment store, increment the register containing the value, compare, and loop.

Comment: I attempted to reply to this comment but the formatting came out incorrect. Perhaps you could take a look at the edited question and offer your opinion? Thanks.

Comment: Looks right. SBRS would be a bit more compact in this specific case, but there's nothing wrong with the code you have.